# Azure Table Storage Bad Request - RequestInformation.Extended​Error​Information null

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

We've been getting a lot of `Bad Request (400)` exceptions when trying to save objects in our table storage, furthermore the storage exception is returning a `null Extended​Error​Information` so i just have the `BadRequest(400)`.

I believe that the value of the properties shouldn't be the problem because our application is deployed on several build configurations and this only happens on one build configuration.

My main doubt is that we have a build configuration with a table name prefix `[buildconfigname]` for the *dev environment* and then a `[buildconfiname]Prod` for the *production environment*. The one that is returning all the `Bad Request` values is the *dev*.

So my question is, can the cause of the bad requests be the fact that one table name prefix contains or is contained in another table name prefix?

Comment: What is the name of the table?

Comment: @GauravMantri The dev table is multitenant and the production is multitenantprod.

Comment: Name of the table is OK. I was able to create a table by this name in my storage account. Can you share the code which is causing this 400 error?

Comment: Have a look at the request/response using Fiddler. That sometimes contains more details than the library passes on

Comment: If possible, could you provide the source code where the exception was thrown?

Comment: you were also mentioning a "prefix" in the question, when you say the dev table name is "multitenant" is this the full name of the table including the prefix ?

Answer (score 0):

> getting a lot of Bad Request (400) exceptions when trying to save objects in our table storage

Many factors can cause “Bad Request (400)” error when making operation on the Table service. Please refer to the following table (or this article: [Table Service Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-error-codes)) and check your code (entity class, entity properties & values etc) to find the cause of the issue.

[image]

Besides, if possible, please share us the code you are using to define your entity class and insert the entity.